# ScrollintoView on Hidded Listbox does not work

Tags: .net, wpf, uiscrollview, controls

I just want to use a `ListBox` and scroll to the last row. Thats no problem as long as the Listbox is visible. But the listbox is on a `TabPage` and when I use another PageIndex and come back to my ListBox, the old item is still selected and scrolled to instead of the last item and the view of the last item.

```
Dim st As New StackPanel
'''some code for stackpanel
Me.List1.Items.Add(st)
Me.List1.ScrollIntoView(st)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're using a `TabControl`, which disposes it's `TabItems` when they're not visible. This means that items are re-created when you switch tabs, so unless values are bound to something in the `DataContext`, they lose their values and revert to the default.

Easiest solution would be to bind the `SelectedItem` to something in the `DataContext`, and be sure new items are getting set as the `SelectedItem` when they're added.

An alternative solution would be to [extend the TabControl to stop it from destorying it's children](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/eburke/archive/2009/04/30/keeping-the-wpf-tab-control-from-destroying-its-children.aspx) when switching tabs

Comment: Hi Rachel. While changing the TabIndex, the TabControl does not rebuild or dispose the controls. Please recheck. I do not rebuild or recreate controls. Just switching the Tab. When moving from TAB1 to TAB3, I change the ListBox selection on TAB3. Then I went to TAB1 and I create new ListEntries for (hidden) TAB3 in codebehind. I switch back to TAB3. New items are created. But the command `ScrollIntoView` did not his work.

Comment: @Nasenbaer If the Template for TabItems is the same, WPF will recycle the displayed item, and not rebuild it. Also if an item is not displayed (such as the ListBox on Tab3 when you're viewing Tab1), it does not exist in the Visual Tree and cannot respond to commands like `ScrollIntoView`. You need to either run the `ScrollIntoView` in the `Loaded` event if TabItems are getting recreated, or in the `DataContextChanged` event if TabItem controls are being reused.

Comment: Thanks Rachel. I could not test it because on my Grid, the Load Event is not called from Page. Its a bit special. Thanks for you interesting answer, I did not know that before.